# Excel - Getting a year range from a single column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to create a year range for multiple identically named cells that have different dates. 
[image: YearRange]

As an example I would want all of the cells named 48947_b580541 to have a year range of 1946-1950. I need to do this for approximately 500k rows of data. Desired output below.

[image]

I haven't been able to find a way to get a range that will change when the source column does. IE the formula would create a year range for years in 48947_b580541 and then start over once it hits 48947_b580542 and create one for that grouping.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have minifs and maxifs (xl2016)?

Comment: Yes I am using the 2016 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all versions,

```
=MIN(INDEX(--(B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH("zzz", A:A)))+(A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH("zzz", A:A))<>A2)*1E+99, , ))&"-"&
 MAX(INDEX(--(B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH("zzz", A:A)))-(A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH("zzz", A:A))<>A2)*1E+99, , ))
```

[image]

For newer versions of excel with the MINIFS/MAXIFS functions, you can simply use,

```
=minifs(b:b, a:a, a2)&"-"&maxifs(b:b, a:a, a2)
```

However, I suspect that the years-as-numbers in column B are actually text-that-look-like-numbers; likely from `left(c2, 4)`. If that is the case, add a double unary to the formula in column B like,

```
=--left(c2, 4)
```

That will convert all results to real numbers that can be read by minifs/maxifs.